# why does static Qt5Sql.lib needs mysql when it is not even used and what to do about it?

Tags: qt, static-linking, qtsql

it seems that I'm stuck trying to build my Qt project with static Qt linking.

after a while trying to static build Qt(which would generate a bunch of .lib files that using them would produce so many LNK errors) I gave up and downloaded the files from https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-qt4-qt5/. now everything is ok except that when I use Qt5Sql.lib I get some LNK2019 error that all of them have QMYSQL in them. the thing is that I did not even use mysql. I used sqlite with the line `static QSqlDatabase cutedb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");`

[my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paDlX.jpg)

there is a strange thing about the build that I downloaded. there is no "sqldrivers" folder in "plugins" folder. but when I built qt myself there was one containing qsqlite.lib and other things.

so why does this happen and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build Qt5Sql from sources without mysql support.